# Displaying search bar query results from an API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, search

I am trying to create a simple app where you find games from an API via a search bar. I am using the Giant Bomb API gem (https://github.com/games-directory/api-giantbomb). The gem seems to be working since I can call things via the console. However, I am not quite sure how to display results or if there are problems with my search method (likely).

Here is my controller for Games:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
//Display search results

  def index
  @games = Game.all.order('created_at DESC')
  @games = @games.search(params[:query]) if params[:query].present?
  end

//Searches through API and redirects to results on index.
  def search
    @games = GiantBomb::Search.new().query(params[:query]).resources('game').limit(5).fetch
    redirect_to index_path
  end


private

  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

My search bar code on my home page:

```
    <div class="search-font"><h1>Build your Collection</h1></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= form_tag search_path class: "row", method: :get do %>
          <div class="col-12 col-sm pr-sm-0">
            <%= text_field_tag :game,
              params[:game],
              class: "form-control input-lg",
              id: "typed-text" %>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-btn ml-3">
            <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And my index.html.erb where it is supposed to spit out the game names.

```
<ul>
  <% @games.each do |game| %>
    <li><%= game.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The search bar redirects but nothing is posted. In my console I can do search.query('Mario') then search.fetch to print out the results, but I am not sure how to use this function in my controller correctly.

[edit] Here are my routes as well.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :games
  root to: 'pages#home'
  get '/search', to: 'games#search', as: :search
  get '/games', to: 'games#index', as: :index
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_to` creates a new request, you need to use `render` as in...

```
render 'index'
```

That way you can use your `@games` variable in the view